# R lapply return empty data frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply

I'm trying to move the data from the list into a data frame. When I run the data path, such as:

`RequestData[["rows"]][["elements"]][[1]][["distance"]][["text"]]`

I get the result:

`[1] "8.4 km"`

But when I use the same path in function:

```
disData <- lapply(seq_along(RequestData), function(x){         
                  Dis_km <- RequestData[["rows"]][["elements"]][[x]][["distance"]][["text"]]
                  Duration <- RequestData[["rows"]][["elements"]][[x]][["duration"]][["text"]]
                  ID <- all_articles[x,"id"]

                  if (is.data.frame(Dis_km) && nrow(Dis_km)>0){

                    res_df <- data.frame(
                                         distanca=Dis_km,
                                         Duration=Duration,
                                         Id = ID
                                                )
                      }
              })
```

The function returns an empty object disData.

**Remark:** Object all_articles in function is another independent data frame.

This data is in the list:
:

```
RequestData
$destination_addresses
[1] "Maršala Tita 62, Sarajevo 71000, Bosnia and Herzegovina"

$origin_addresses
 [1] "Mustafe Latifića, Sarajevo 71000, Bosnia and Herzegovina"         "Porodice Ribar, Sarajevo 71000, Bosnia and Herzegovina"          
 [3] "Skenderija & Adila Grebe, Sarajevo 71000, Bosnia and Herzegovina" "Azize Šaćirbegović, Sarajevo 71000, Bosnia and Herzegovina"      
 [5] "Bosanska, Sarajevo 71000, Bosnia and Herzegovina"                 "Jezero, Sarajevo 71000, Bosnia and Herzegovina"                  
 [7] "Behdžeta Mutevelića, Sarajevo 71000, Bosnia and Herzegovina"      "Emila Zole, Sarajevo 71000, Bosnia and Herzegovina"              
 [9] "Braće Begić, Sarajevo 71000, Bosnia and Herzegovina"              "Porodice Ribar, Sarajevo 71000, Bosnia and Herzegovina"          
[11] "Nedima Filipovića, Sarajevo 71000, Bosnia and Herzegovina"        "Telali, Sarajevo 71000, Bosnia and Herzegovina"                  
[13] "Ohridska, Sarajevo, Bosnia and Herzegovina"                       "Muse Ćazima Ćatića, Sarajevo 71000, Bosnia and Herzegovina"      
[15] "Džemala Bijedića, Sarajevo, Bosnia and Herzegovina"               "Ferde Hauptmana, Sarajevo 71000, Bosnia and Herzegovina"         
[17] "Bakarevićeva & Bistrik, Sarajevo 71000, Bosnia and Herzegovina"   "Vratnik Mejdan, Sarajevo 71000, Bosnia and Herzegovina"          
[19] "Mis Irbina, Sarajevo 71000, Bosnia and Herzegovina"               "Koševo, Sarajevo 71000, Bosnia and Herzegovina"                  

$rows
                                 elements
1  8.4 km, 8432, 1 hour 47 mins, 6413, OK
2         3.5 km, 3538, 46 mins, 2779, OK
3            0.7 km, 692, 9 mins, 552, OK
4         3.9 km, 3863, 50 mins, 3023, OK
5  6.3 km, 6275, 1 hour 19 mins, 4761, OK
6           0.8 km, 838, 11 mins, 655, OK
7         3.2 km, 3196, 41 mins, 2460, OK
8  7.9 km, 7898, 1 hour 43 mins, 6163, OK
9         2.4 km, 2413, 31 mins, 1842, OK
10        3.5 km, 3538, 46 mins, 2779, OK
11        4.0 km, 4041, 53 mins, 3165, OK
12          0.9 km, 937, 12 mins, 713, OK
13        2.8 km, 2837, 41 mins, 2432, OK
14           0.6 km, 611, 7 mins, 438, OK
15        4.5 km, 4507, 59 mins, 3550, OK
16        4.0 km, 4034, 53 mins, 3162, OK
17         1.0 km, 1039, 14 mins, 814, OK
18        1.6 km, 1564, 20 mins, 1215, OK
19           0.6 km, 595, 8 mins, 470, OK
20        1.9 km, 1883, 24 mins, 1425, OK

$status
[1] "OK"
```

The list structure looks like this with first element:

[image]

What's the problem? 
Thank you!

Comment: In the dataframe do you expect destination_addresses and status to be repeated with values given for all rows or only for first row and null for the rest?

Comment: Not. I just want to get values from path $rows$elements$distance and path $rows$elements$duration, then merge them with the id from another dataframe (all_articles)

Comment: Also can you share the structure of elements of the list apparently there is a dataframe in element rows however it is not clear what column names it contains. There is also reference to all_articles which is not clear what it refers to.

Comment: I added the necessary information.

Comment: Please check the answer given

Comment: Please add the data using `dput`. It is difficult to recreate data with same structure as yours and hence, makes it difficult to debug as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is a better way than using apply family to solve your problem with which also you will have full control of your dataframe and can easily manipulate it, mostly you will use dplyr and purrr packages as follows;

#### Elements Creation

```
# Creating original list
destination_addresses = c("Maršala Tita 62, Sarajevo 71000, Bosnia and Herzegovina")

origin_addresses = c("Mustafe Latifića, Sarajevo 71000, Bosnia and Herzegovina",
                     "Porodice Ribar, Sarajevo 71000, Bosnia and Herzegovina",
                     "Skenderija & Adila Grebe, Sarajevo 71000, Bosnia and Herzegovina",
                     "Azize Šaćirbegović, Sarajevo 71000, Bosnia and Herzegovina",   
                     "Bosanska, Sarajevo 71000, Bosnia and Herzegovina",
                     "Jezero, Sarajevo 71000, Bosnia and Herzegovina",
                     "Behdžeta Mutevelića, Sarajevo 71000, Bosnia and Herzegovina",
                     "Emila Zole, Sarajevo 71000, Bosnia and Herzegovina",
                     "Braće Begić, Sarajevo 71000, Bosnia and Herzegovina",
                     "Porodice Ribar, Sarajevo 71000, Bosnia and Herzegovina",
                     "Nedima Filipovića, Sarajevo 71000, Bosnia and Herzegovina",
                     "Telali, Sarajevo 71000, Bosnia and Herzegovina",
                     "Ohridska, Sarajevo, Bosnia and Herzegovina",
                     "Muse Ćazima Ćatića, Sarajevo 71000, Bosnia and Herzegovina",
                     "Džemala Bijedića, Sarajevo, Bosnia and Herzegovina",
                     "Ferde Hauptmana, Sarajevo 71000, Bosnia and Herzegovina",
                     "Bakarevićeva & Bistrik, Sarajevo 71000, Bosnia and Herzegovina",
                     "Vratnik Mejdan, Sarajevo 71000, Bosnia and Herzegovina",
                     "Mis Irbina, Sarajevo 71000, Bosnia and Herzegovina",
                     "Koševo, Sarajevo 71000, Bosnia and Herzegovina")

status = c("OK")

# Please note this is a sample of rows only
rows <- list(elements = list(
  list(distance = data.frame(text = c("8.4 km"), value = 8432, stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
       duration = data.frame(text = c("1 hour 47 mins"), value = 6413, 
                             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)),
  list(distance = data.frame(text = c("3.5 km"), value = 8432, stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
       duration = data.frame(text = c("46 mins"), value = 6413, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))))

# Creating final list
RequestData <- list(
  destination_addresses = destination_addresses,
  origin_addresses = origin_addresses,
  rows = rows,
  status = status
)

# All articles dataframe
all_articles <-
  data.frame(
    id = c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4", "ID5", "ID6")
  )
```

#### Method 1: using map function (Recommended)

Steps:

I will loop on RequestData$rows$elements so that the output would be a dataframe
2. In each element I will loop on its elements i.e. RequestData$rows$elements[[1]]
3. Then I will convert this element into a dataframe
4. Now after the two loops are done map_df will automatically bind everything into dataframe

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

disData <-
  1:length(RequestData$rows$elements) %>% # We loop on elements
  map_df(function(x){
    tibble( # Access required elements from list
      distance = RequestData$rows$elements[[x]][["distance"]][["text"]],
      duration = RequestData$rows$elements[[x]][["duration"]][["text"]],
      Id = all_articles[x, "id"])
  })

disData
# # A tibble: 2 x 3
# distance duration       Id   
# <chr>    <chr>          <fct>
# 8.4 km   1 hour 47 mins ID1  
# 3.5 km   46 mins        ID2
```

#### Method 2: Using lapply

If you wish to keep it with lapply as you have created it, the following are the issues with the code

1. It should be seq_along(RequestData$rows$elements) because you want to loop on elements
2. if (is.data.frame(Dis_km) && nrow(Dis_km)>0) will never be true because Dis_km is a single character not a dataframe, here the dataframe is RequestData$rows$elements[[1]]
3. The result of lapply will be list of dataframes you will need to bind them to convert it into a single dataframe

Here is the code after fixing;

```
disData <- lapply(seq_along(RequestData$rows$elements), function(x){  
  Dis_km <- RequestData[["rows"]][["elements"]][[x]][["distance"]][["text"]]
  Duration <- RequestData[["rows"]][["elements"]][[x]][["duration"]][["text"]]
  ID <- all_articles[x,"id"]

  if (length(Dis_km) > 0){
    res_df <- data.frame(
      distanca = Dis_km,
      Duration = Duration,
      Id = ID
    )
  }
})

disData <- do.call("rbind", disData)
disData
# distanca       Duration  Id
# 8.4 km 1 hour 47 mins ID1
# 3.5 km        46 mins ID2
```

Comment: Thanks Naramen. I'll take the first example.